# Не приходят письма подтверждения регистрации Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, apache2

С сайта не отправляются письма для подтверждения регистрации пользователем и только эти письма, во всех остальных случаях письма отправляются. Хотя система пишет что вам отправлено письмо для подтверждения почты. Не отправляются они ни со стандартной формы, ни посредством сторонних плагинов, например BuddyPress. Может кто то подсказать где необходимо копать чтоб выявить проблему?

Comment: Опять угадайка. Какие-то плагины на сайте, что-то делают... Отключите все плагины по одному, смените тему на стандартную, локализуйте проблему. Потом приходите.

Comment: Не очень помогли, но спасибо. Если бы я мог прямо сейчас отключить все плагины, я бы это сделал. На сайте сейчас 2к+ хостов в сутки, сайт посыплется.

Comment: Никто не работает на продакшен, это как минимум непрофессионально. У вас должна быть локальная копия сайта для тестов.

Comment: Пока что git не внедрен, но вопрос надо решать уже сейчас. Возможно кто то просто сталкивался с чем то подобным, может быть есть варианты отключить где либо еще отправку писем при регистрации.

Comment: Сделайте так, чтобы работала ф-ция wp_mail

Comment: А при проверке через плагин check email не она отрабатывает? Мне кажется должна стандартно она отправлять. Данный плагин отправляет почту успешно как и форма обратной связи, не отправляется только при регистрации, даже при восстановлении пароля отправляется.

Comment: Прежде всего надо смотреть почтовые логи. Наиболее просто для нубов - с помощью специальных плагинов.

Comment: Спасибо, поставил mail log, при отправлении тестового письма через SMTP в логе данное письмо отображается, однако при регистрации юзера там ничего не появляется, хотя система пишет что вам отправлено письмо с подтверждением регистрации

Comment: Могут ли какие либо плагины отвязать от соответствующего экшена функцию отправки сообщения? Как это вообще можно проверить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перепробовал все, проблему удалось решить удалением плагина reCaptcha by WPform и последующим отключением, включением темы, возможно были какие то конфликты с подключаемыми в ней скриптами.